# In VEGAN ADONIS, what does "method='bray' do when I pass in a distance matrix I already have (UNIFRAC)?

Tags: distance, permutation-test, manova, diversity, vegan

Suppose I have a distance matrix created by applying the weighted unifrac measure. For instance, using a `phyloseq` object:

```
weighted_unifrac = UniFrac(
  physeq=ps,
  weighted=T,
  normalized=T,
  parallel=T,
  fast=T
)
```

`weighted_unifrac` is now a distance matrix. Then I perform PERMANOVA using `adonis`, and showing the default `method` parameter:

```
permanova = adonis(
  formula=weighted_unifrac ~ CaseString, 
  data=sample_data,
  permutations=999,
  method='bray'
  )
```

What is `method` doing here? I think of Bray-Curtis as a way to generate the distance matrix itself. How does `method="bray"` or my choice of another `method` value affect my PERMANOVA analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `adonis` you can provide either a dissimilarity matrix or a community data matrix.  If the left hand side of your formula is a community data matrix, `adonis` will use the `vegdist` function to calculate a dissimilarity matrix using the `method` you've specified (Bray-Curtis by default).  If the left hand side of your formula is a dissimilarity matrix then this step is skipped, and `method` is ignored.

Short answer: "method" doesn't do anything when you pass in a distance matrix